# Weird 'undefined reference' error

Tags: c++

I have run into a peculiar error in a C++ project at work.

I have found a fix, but I am now really satisfied, as I would like to understand what actually causes the error.

When building this snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "snmp/snmp/SW_SNMP_Values.hpp"
#include "snmp/agent/SW_Agent.hpp"
#include "snmp/agent/SW_Agent_PP.hpp"

int main()
{
    //SW_Agent_PP agent;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that SW_Agent_PP is COMMENTED OUT!! When building this, I get a ton of undefined reference errors, for classes that are in use by the SW_Agent_PP object.

The FIX is to ACTUALLY CREATE THE OBJECT! so if I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "snmp/snmp/SW_SNMP_Values.hpp"
#include "snmp/agent/SW_Agent.hpp"
#include "snmp/agent/SW_Agent_PP.hpp"

int main()
{
    SW_Agent_PP agent;

    return 0;
}
```

everything works fine and dandy.

How can I get linker errors for NOT using something? I would like to hear if anyone have run into similar experiences before, and if they found what caused it.

I am sorry, but I cannot release more code as it is company property.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the definition of `SW_Agent_PP`? Is is a macro?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in one of the .hpp files. possibly a missing semicolon.

Comment: complete class. Split into header and .cpp file

Comment: If you can't give us your actual code, then construct an *equivalent* test case that still exhibits the problem, and then post the code for that.  If we can't see your code, then how can we possibly help?

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree Oli :) but as I am not really looking for a fix, as I have already fixed it, I was just interested if anybody had similar experiences before, and knew what could cause such an error

Comment: @Daniel I wouldn't call what you've done a fix but a temporary workaround. I would feel very uneasy continuing to use this code without knowing why it acts so strangely. Often these issues point to deeper issues that can really cost you later down the road. Better to get to the bottom of it now.

Comment: exactly, Doug. Hence my question here. And I am sorry for not providing more code, but as I don't have ANY clue as to where the error lies, it is a tad bit difficult to construct an equivalent test case as Oli puts it, which shows the same error.

Comment: You may experiment a bit by commenting out the includes or renaming the agent object and see if it gives any clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linkers are complicated and this behaviour is by no means unusual. Here's one possible explanation:

1. You are linking with a static library `libfoo.a`.
2. `libfoo.a` contains `foo.o` that contains `SW_Agent_PP::SW_Agent_PP()` and a bunch of other functions.
3. Another library `libbar.a`, listed after `libfoo.a` in the link line, uses a bunch of other functions from `libfoo.a`.

The linker processes static libraries in order and never goes back. Therefore the references in `libbar.a` can be only satisfied if corresponding object was pulled from `libfoo.a` by `main()`.

The solution is to reorder the libraries in the link line.

There are other possible explanations. It's hard to tell without seeing actual code.